# Find the numbers a, b integer satisfy $(a-b)(a+b)=8^c+10$

Tags: linear-algebra, integers

Find the numbers a, b integer satisfy $$(a-b)(a+b)=8^c+10$$

---

*)$c=0\Rightarrow (a-b)(a+b)=11=5*6=6*5=1*11=11*1$

$\Rightarrow a=±6;b=±5$

*)About $c\ne0$ i can't solve. Help

Comment: $11=5*6=6*5$? Typo?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $c>0$, $8^c+10\equiv 2$ (mod $4$).

Note that $a^2\equiv 0$ or $1$ (mod $4$) and $b^2\equiv 0$ or $1$ (mod $4$)

It is impossible that $a^2-b^2\equiv 2$ (mod $4$).

Comment: I was just writing the same answer $\mod{8}$ but I guess $\mod{4}$ works just as well.

Comment: if $c<0$ ......

Comment: If $c$ is a negative integer, then $8^c+10$ is not an integer and the equation has no solution.